Relationship between varying radius of ball and its affect on time taken for ball to come to rest in a spherical hemisphere while moving in a circle
I am a high school student trying to figure out the theoretical relationship between the radius of a ball that is launched into a bowl (moves in a circular path in the bowl) and the time taken for it to come to a stop. I did some trials and found out the the smaller the radius is the shorter the time taken for it to come to a stop in a bowl of fixed curvature and radius. The only thing varied is the radius of the ball that enters the bowl and the initial velocity while entering the bowl was kept the same. It would be helpful if someone could help explain how I can go about deriving this relationship.

I feel like you have to change more than just the radius. Does the mass change? Material of the ball? Both?

You need to look up rolling resistance.

If i change the radius the mass will change. pv = m. Material is constant though
